# Calling a react component by passing state exception

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I tried to render the table from `MapContainer`
After I grabbed the data from server, I will render `TransactionTable` component.

Is this a bug from 'react-table' or am I using it the wrong way for this data flow?

> Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string
>   (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite
>   components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your
>   component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up
>   default and named imports.
>
> Check the render method of `TransactionTable`.

Also,

> Uncaught Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined.

## MapContainer.tsx

```
class MapContainer extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            transactions: []
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        let self = this
        axios.get("http://localhost:8080/api/v1/XXXX", {}).then(resp => {
            console.table(resp)
            self.setState({transactions: resp.data})
            self.forceUpdate()
        }).catch((e) => {
            console.log(e)
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <GoogleMap
                    defaultZoom={16}
                    defaultCenter={{lat: 25.0389801, lng: 121.5272577}}
                    defaultOptions={{styles: null}}
                >
                    {this.state.transactions && this.state.transactions.map(transaction => (
                        <Item data={transaction}/>
                    ))}

                </GoogleMap>
                {this.state.transactions && <TransactionTable data={this.state.transactions}/>}
            </div>
        )

    }
}
```

## TransactionTable.tsx

```
import React, {useState, useEffect, Component} from "react";
import { useTable, useSortBy } from 'react-table'
import {ReactTable} from 'react-table'


class TransactionTable extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        console.log(props)
        this.state = {
            data: props.data
        };
    }
    render() {
        const { data } = this.state;
        console.log("RECEIVED data")
        console.table(data)
        return (
            <div>
                <h1> Table </h1>
                <ReactTable
                    data={data}
                    columns={[
                        {
                            Header: "Name",
                            columns: [
                                {
                                    Header: "First Name (Sorted by Length, A-Z)",
                                    accessor: "transaction_id"
                                },
                                {
                                    Header: "Last Name (Sorted in reverse, A-Z)",
                                    id: "lastName",
                                    accessor: d => d.address
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            Header: "Info",
                            columns: [
                                {
                                    Header: "estimate_address",
                                    accessor: "estimate_address"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]}
                    defaultPageSize={10}
                    className="-striped -highlight"
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default TransactionTable
```

## Update

Tried this way to import **ReactTable** but still not working.

> import ReactTable from 'react-table'

Comment: Just like the error message says, you have mixed up default and named imports. It should be `import ReactTable from 'react-table'` without the brackets.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Element type is invalid, you likely forgot to export your component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46737778/element-type-is-invalid-you-likely-forgot-to-export-your-component)

Comment: Won't work. Same exception :(

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to import ReactTable is `import ReactTable from 'react-table';`

Comment: check if the values of data and columns of ReactTable are assigned in the format mentioned in the ref: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-table